# Active Model Serializer 0.10 filter on query params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers, rails-api

Looking through the other questions, it seems that 0.10 no longer supports the old methods of filtering on query params.

```
class CategorySerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name, :deals_count

  def deals_count
    byebug
    Deal.includes(:categories).where(categories: { id: @object.id }).count
  end

end
```

On the deals model, I have booleans for each day of the week (monday, tuesday, wednesday ... )

I want to be able to pass in `(tuesday=true&, wednesday=true)` etc as filters to add for this.

Comment: what do you mean old? 0.10 version supports 0.8 version of method set.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `instance_options`.

```
# controller
render json: @category, days: [1, 2, 4, 6, 7]
```

And your serializer should be something like:

```
class CategorySerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name, :deals_count

  def deals_count
    Deal.where(days: instance_options[:days])
      .includes(:categories).where(categories: { id: @object.id } ).count
  end
end
```

*Note:* any options passed to render that are not reserved for the adapter should be available

Comment: Good answer. Can also use serialization scope